# layout_gravity="right" don't make controls to right side in LinearLayout

Tags: android

In the following layout , I think the three controls textTotalTitle,textTotalValue and chAll will locate the right side of UI,
but in fact, the three controls still stay the left side, why?

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="#DCDCDC"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textSMSFilter"
            style="@style/myTextAppearance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="4dip"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/filter" >
        </TextView>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerMsgFolder"
            android:layout_width="133dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTotalTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
             android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/totalAndSelectedTitle" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTotalValue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="3dip"
            android:paddingRight="2dip"
             android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:text="0/1" >
        </TextView>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chAll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:paddingRight="5dip" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use relative layout mate

Comment: I concur. Using Linear sometime means you have to have multiple layout. You have to mix and match until you get the desired result.

Comment: How is any of this going up any side with it being a linear layout horizontal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because if `android:orientation` of `LinearLayout` is `horizontal`, the `android:layout_gravity's` value **right and left will be not working**.
You can only **set it to top or bottom**. 
And if `LinearLayout` is `vertical`, you can set `layout_gravity` **to left or right, but not top or bottom**. 
 So, I think you should use `RelativeLayout` here...